# Longest Increasing Subsequence in linear time?

Tags: algorithms

What is the optimal time complexity for an algorithm that solves the Longest Increasing Subsequence problem?

I am aware of the O(n log n) algorithm mentioned in textbooks (and on the [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence)). Can we do better? Is it possible to solve this problem in O(n) time?

Comment: "Tight Ω(n lg n) lower bound for finding a longest increasing subsequence" (which I don't have access to) claims that the answer is No. But you can get sublinear time if you only want to estimate the length: ["Estimating the Longest Increasing Subsequence in Nearly Optimal Time"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.05106.pdf).

Comment: The $\Omega(n\log n)$ lower bound is in the decision tree model and its extensions. In particular, it doesn't apply when the alphabet is fixed.